# Как посчитать количество цифр в числе (число начинается на ноль)

Tags: c++

Вот пример который я нашёл в интернете:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
cout << (x==0? 1: int (log10 (x) + 1));
```

Но если число начинается на ноль, этот алгоритм его не учитывает.

Comment: Что значит начинается на 0? Приведите пример.

Comment: А что значит "начинается на ноль"? 00033 ил 00000033? А вообще, простейший в смысле кодирования способ - `to_string(x).length()` :)

Comment: как оно может начинаться на 0, это же int

Comment: @Harry и так и так, ну например 033 =3 цифри.
0094 =4 цифри.

Comment: @Witalik, так 0094 и 094 это одно и тоже число: 94

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А, понял. Вы вводите эти цифры сами...
Тогда

```
string x;
cin >> x;
cout << x.length();
```

Просто потому что если читать не строку, а число - то введете вы `00094` или `94` - в вашем `x` будет одно и то же число...

Comment: А как тогда после из него "взять" первую, вторую и последующие цифры?
Мне вот например нужно чтобы цифры на парных местах додавались, на непарных перемножались и этого всего найти суму.

Comment: `x[0]` - первая цифра (как символ! чтобы получить ее числовое значение, нужно вычитать символ ноля - `x[0]-'0'`), `x[1]` - вторая и так далее...

Comment: Как я понимаю это массив, но как _вычитать символ ноля_ я так и не понял....

Comment: Я же написал:    `x[0]-'0'`. Просто перенести в свой код можете? Выделить, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V?